# Call a function of a file .m in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, call

I have a file .m and I want call a function of file .m.
For example, I have the file MdeD.m:

```
function ESC = EDLECE(HOJA,POSF,POSC)

fid = fopen(HOJA,'r','n','UTF-8');
for i=1:POSF
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
COL = '%s';
for i=2:POSC-1
    COL = strcat(COL, ' %s');
end
ESC = textscan(tline,strcat(COL,' %d'));
ESC = ESC{1,POSC};
end
```

and I want call the function EDLECE in another file .m. How do I do it?

(I sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

Save the function in a file with the same name as the function and the .m file extension. In this case, it would be **EDLECE.m**. Put the file in the current working directory or in any directory in your search path.

From the other .m file, just call the function by it's name, like this:

```
ESC = EDLECE(HOJA,POSF,POSC);
```

Click [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pathtool.html) for instructions on how to view/modify your search path.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the file `MdeD.m` contains only the function `EDLECE` or whether `EDLECE.m` is a subfunction in `MdeD.m`.

If `MdeD.m` only contains the `EDLECE` function, then you should really name the file `EDLECE.m` and you should be able to use the function just like any Matlab function as long as `EDLECE.m` is in your search path.

On the other hand, if `EDLECE` is a subfunction in `MdeD.m`, then you can't use it from another function/script or the command window. You will have to pull it out of `MdeD` and save it as its own function.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Yes, EDLECE is a subfunction in MdeD.m and I want call EDLECE from MdeD.m, then, you know any way to do that or is imposible.